# How to retrive stripe data from stripe webhook event in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, stripe-payments, webhooks

When implementing stripe webhook in rails, I am successful in getting the event object in JSON format. But the problem is I am not able to get the details like the amount, subscription_id, attributes which are in nested JSON. Getting these values from the class object is also not available. Could you please tell me how to extract these values.

```
invoice = Stripe::Invoice.retrieve(:id => "in_1AwVDUHb727hqFGZ0UF7B8tB")
```

And I get the following response :

```
#<Stripe::Invoice:0xebc79c id=in_1AwVDUHb727hqFGZ0UF7B8tB> JSON: {
  "id": "in_1AwVDUHb727hqFGZ0UF7B8tB",
  "object": "invoice",
  "amount_due": 2500,
  "application_fee": null,
  "attempt_count": 1,
  "attempted": true,
  "billing": "charge_automatically",
  "charge": "ch_1AwVDUHb727hqFGZ702PYTrW",
  "closed": true,
  "currency": "aud",
  "customer": "cus_BJ7S8vrsbh9Lyj",
  "date": 1504095764,
  "description": null,
  "discount": null,
  "ending_balance": 0,
  "forgiven": false,
  "lines": {"object":"list","data":[{"id":"sub_BJ7ScT0lf9yVGV","object":"line_item","amount":2500,"currency":"aud","description":null,"discountable":true,"livemode":false,"metadata":{},"period":{"start":1504095764,"end":1506774164},"plan":{"id":"c844d552154b","object":"plan","amount":2500,"created":1504095762,"currency":"aud","interval":"month","interval_count":1,"livemode":false,"metadata":{},"name":"Plan2","statement_descriptor":null,"trial_period_days":null},"proration":false,"quantity":1,"subscription":null,"subscription_item":"si_1AwVDUHb727hqFGZh2iulZFY","type":"subscription"}],"has_more":false,"total_count":1,"url":"/v1/invoices/in_1AwVDUHb727hqFGZ0UF7B8tB/lines"},
  "livemode": false,
  "metadata": {},
  "next_payment_attempt": null,
  "number": "7b726e08d6-0001",
  "paid": true,
  "period_end": 1504095764,
  "period_start": 1504095764,
  "receipt_number": null,
  "starting_balance": 0,
  "statement_descriptor": null,
  "subscription": "sub_BJ7ScT0lf9yVGV",
  "subtotal": 2500,
  "tax": null,
  "tax_percent": null,
  "total": 2500,
  "webhooks_delivered_at": 1504095765
}
```

I want to get the values like the customer_id, subscription_id, plan_id , etc.
How would I extract the data.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you've [retrieved the invoice](https://stripe.com/docs/api#retrieve_invoice), you can simply access the object's attribute, e.g.:

```
invoice = Stripe::Invoice.retrieve("in_...")
customer_id = invoice.customer
subscription_id = invoice.subscription
```

The invoice doesn't carry the plan's ID, so you'd need to [retrieve the subscription](https://stripe.com/docs/api#retrieve_subscription) first:

```
subscription = Stripe::Subscription.retrieve(subscription_id)
plan_id = subscription.plan
```